# Is it possible to maximize windows vertically in Gnome 3 by double click on the top border?

Tags: gnome, window-management

I would like to maximize windows vertically by double clicking on the horizontal boarder like in Windows. Is there a way to get this behavior in Gnome Shell?

Thanks in Advance

Edit: I forgot to mention that I mean double click.

Like in this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UulpXn0Tu_o)

Comment: I am unsure what you mean, but: Double-clicking the top window bar in Gnome will maximize the window. However, I am not sure if what you actually want is to resize the window, or want the maximize button back on the top bar? Could you please explain further.

Comment: I do not mean the Titlebar, but the border of the Window. By clicking and dragging the border you can change the window size. That position is meant.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** There is no way to use the border of a window. You can only use the title bar. Open a terminal an use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-double-click-titlebar toggle-maximize-vertically
```

---

Check the settings with:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-double-click-titlebar
```

Or you can try the other options:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-double-click-titlebar OPTION
```

`OPTION` – Current valid options are 'toggle-shade', which will shade/unshade the window, 'toggle-maximize' which will maximize/unmaximize the window, 'toggle-maximize-horizontally' and 'toggle-maximize-vertically' which will 'minimize' which will minimize the window, 'shade' which will roll the window up, 'menu' which will display the window menu, 'lower' which will put the window behind all the others, and 'none' which will not do anything.

Comment: Best answer.  I wish I could upvote twice!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Than you should give me at least one upvote :P ;)

Comment: Oops!!! Forgot!  ;-)

Comment: Please keep in mind that due to the following bug, apps with a "Gnome" titlebar (the broad one) won't maximize vertically or horizontally, but always fully: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1698083

Answer (score 5):

Not for the border, but for the titlebar. `gnome-tweak-tool` will let you do this:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/

For example:

Windows > Titlebar Actions > Middle-Click > select [Toggle Maximize Vertically]

Comment: Does this only work on some applications? It seems to never work for me. A middle click always fully maximizes.

Comment: The above setting works only with windows that use "native window borders", not with any application that uses CSD (Client Side Decorations). In addition, the maximize vertically is always broken if you use Wayland instead of Xorg to run your display. This cannot be easily fixed because maximize vertically used to be window manager operation and Wayland requires apps to manage their own windows but Wayland protocol doesn't support the concept of maximize vertically. The only way to get this fixed is to first fix the protocol and then all CSD apps.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate approach: If you middle click the square (orange x, grey -, grey square)

[image]

then the window will maximize vertically. I've done that a few times on accident.  Glad to finally figure out what random key stroke caused that.

Comment: From my point of view, this is the best method/answer. Also, doing it in this manner I don't lose windows minimizing capability middle clicking title bar.

Comment: However, not all windows respect this behavior _(IntelliJ, Phpstorm and other Java apps for example)_

Answer (score 3):

I use a keyboard shortcut.

Go to Settings, Keyboard, Shortcuts, Windows. Then change 'Maximize window vertically'. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.

Comment: I tried this, but the window is still being maximized fully (not only vertically). 15.04

Comment: worked for me on centos7

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 19.10.